# How to add classes to images based on their categories?

Tags: functions, images, attachments, categories

I need to be able to: 1.) assign categories to images and 2.) add classes to all images that correspond to their assigned categories.

I was able to add categories to images with the following:

```
function ug_add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'ug_add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

And I found a function to add a class to images as so:

```
function add_image_class($class){
    $class .= ' additional-class';
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class');
```

But I'm not advanced enough with php to take it much further. I tried this

```
function ug_add_image_class($class){
    foreach(get_the_category() as $cat) { $class .= ' category-'.$cat->slug; };
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','ug_add_image_class');
```

but no love...

Help? Ideas? Please? and Happy Friday!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should hopefully do the trick:

```
/**
 * Append the image categories to the current image class.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156576/26350
 */

add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', 
    function( $class, $id, $align, $size )
    {
        foreach( (array) get_the_category( $id ) as $cat ) 
        { 
            $class .= ' category-' . $cat->slug; 
        }
        return $class;
    }
, 10, 4 );
```

### Testing (WP 3.9.1):

If we set the image categories as (for example):

```
rolling-stones, steel-wheels-tour, wembley
```

*Screenshot:*

[image: image categories]

and then insert the image into the post, we get the extra classes as expected:

```
category-rolling-stones category-steel-wheels-tour category-wembley
```

*Screenshot:*

[image: html]

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks much... you're the official 'hero of the day!'

Comment: @heytricia Great to hear it worked for you, I will check out ["Hero of the Day"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGY6aAhF77E) by Metallica on their 1996 album Load and enjoy it for the rest of the day, thanks ;-)

Comment: So how hard would it be to modify this and add the categories to a rel attribute?  I'm thinking this would be a better approach to image filtering.

Comment: @heytricia I updated my answer, but it's untested.

Comment: @birgire Great band, great song, and great answer

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks - WordPress is much better with music ;-)

Comment: @birgire - Tried the mod version, but no love.  When I tried to re-add an image, nothing happened.  Switched back and was able to add.  What's up with your PHP cape, Mister!  Super heroes never falter.  ;-)

I should probably post as a new question....  And guys... don't you know Macklemore and Lewis are the best for heisting your way thru code?!

Comment: @birgire - [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158021/how-to-add-a-rel-attribute-to-images-that-contains-their-categories]

Comment: @heytricia, There was a little bit of *Kryptonite* in the `sprintf` function, i.e. I had a silly typo in the function name itself ;-) I moved the `rel` part it to your other question. I hope it will work now ;-)

Comment: @birgire - well apparently Kryptonite isn't enough to hold back Captain PHP. Thanks again for your help on this.