# How to add a rel attribute to images that contains their categories?

Tags: functions, images, attachments, categories, customization

I've added categories to images, so that I can use them to filter images within a portfolio page.  Now I'm thinking I need to add the rel attribute to each image that contains its assigned categories.  Is this the right approach?  If so, how do I add add rel with the applicable categories?

Comment: The `rel` attribute is only valid on links. (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

Comment: @mrwweb Thanks for the heads-up on the rel tag. I decided to go with data-filter, which conforms to standards and is a better fit for the jquery plugin I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for the `rel` attribute:

```
/**
 * Create a rel attribute from the image categories
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158024/26350
 */

add_filter( 'get_image_tag', 
    function( $html, $id )
    {
        $rel = array();

        foreach( (array) get_the_category( $id ) as $cat ) 
        { 
            $rel[] = $cat->slug; 
        }

        return str_ireplace( 
            '<img ', 
            sprintf( '<img rel="%s" ', join( ' ', $rel ) ),
            $html
        );
    }
, 10, 2 );
```

where we use the `get_image_tag` filter to modify the inserted image HTML.

*Ps*: I just tested this successfully on my WordPress 3.9.2 install, where I used the following code snippet:

```
add_action( 'init',
    function()   
    {
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
    }
);
```

to activate the *categories* for *attachments*.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Many thanks!  Though @mrwweb makes a good point. I researched to see if I could use more than one value in the rel attr, but didn't know it was meant only for links. I may have to think through this approach.  I've seen it used so many ways, and the w3c validator can be antiquated - so I'm used to ignoring any rel related errors.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying slightly to use data-filter instead of rel. Works perfectly and complies with standards.

```
add_filter( 'get_image_tag', 
    function( $html, $id )
    {
        $dataFilter = array();

        foreach( (array) get_the_category( $id ) as $cat ) 
        { 
            $dataFilter[] = $cat->slug; 
        }

        return str_ireplace( 
            '<img ', 
            sprintf( '<img data-filter="%s" ', join( ' ', $dataFilter ) ),
            $html
        );
    }
, 10, 2 );
```